# Stopping Invoke when remove eventHandler

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working on an application c# (I'm not the only one developer and I'm a beginner on thread management).

When I close the application, I call a function to stop the camera running (using directshow.NET). This function needs that all thread are ended. I've a trouble with a function in wait mode, it prevent for the end.

The code :

```
void capGrabber_NewFrameArrived(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Dispatcher != null)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Render, (SendOrPostCallback)delegate
        {
            if (BitmapSource != null)
            {
                BitmapSource.Invalidate();
                UpdateFramerate();
            }
        }, null);
    }
}

void Stop()
{
    capGrabber.NewFrameArrived -= new EventHandler(capGrabber_NewFrameArrived);
    IMediaControl mediaCtrl = m_FilterGraph as IMediaControl;
    mediaCtrl.Stop();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(m_FilterGraph);
}
```

Actually The main thread is blocked on `mediaCtrl.Stop()`. I've stop the execution and I see a working thread blocked :

> WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.DispatcherOperationEvent.WaitOne
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, long millisecondsTimeout, bool hasThreadAffinity, bool exitContext)
>   mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(System.TimeSpan timeout, bool exitContext)
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.DispatcherOperationEvent.WaitOne()
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Wait(System.TimeSpan timeout)
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation operation, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, System.TimeSpan timeout)
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)
>   WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.Delegate method, object arg)
>   WpfCap.dll!WpfCap.CapDevice.capGrabber_NewFrameArrived(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
>   WpfCap.dll!WpfCap.CapGrabber.OnNewFrameArrived()
>   WpfCap.dll!WpfCap.CapGrabber.BufferCB(double sampleTime, System.IntPtr buffer, int bufferLen)

I suppose that when I remove method `capGrabber_NewFrameArrived` from the EventHandler `NewFrameArrived` it doesn't stop execution. How can I force the thread close before doing the `capGrabber.NewFrameArrived -= new EventHandler(capGrabber_NewFrameArrived);` ?

Comment: It is a standard deadlock, always an issue when you use Invoke().  The grabber cannot stop until its event completes, the event cannot complete because your UI thread is stuck on the Stop() method and not dispatching anymore.  A quick fix is to use BeginInvoke() instead so the event can't get stuck.  If that doesn't work then the next quick fix is to not call Stop() at all.  If that doesn't work then use a worker thread to call Stop().  If that doesn't work then you'll have to delay closing your window with a timer.

Comment: I've replaced `Invoke` by `BeginInvoke` and it seems to work (I had not always the deadlock so I'll see the use if it comme back). What's the difference between `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke` ?

Comment: Invoke() blocks until the invoked code runs to completion, BeginInvoke doesn't.  The blocking is what significantly increases the risk for deadlock.  Sometimes you *must* use Invoke(), when the event data has limited lifetime or is not thread-safe.  In the case of a grabber that might happen if the bitmap is destroyed when the event is complete.  Which is quite common and would normally produce a loud bang, seems that doesn't happen in your case.  Watch out for an out-of-memory problem.